# Convert date time in R to date time for time series

Tags: r

I have this dataframe where DT is in char, i would like to convert it into date time format in R so that i can plot a time series

```
DT                  Name 
12-12-21 1:30       James
01-01-22 12:30      Job
03-02-22 1:00       Seth
03-02-22 1:14       Michael
```

I explored the following code

```
time <- as.POSIXct(dataframe$DT, format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

but it returned year as 01-01-0021 instead of 01-01-2021, may i know how could i specify the year so that it could be read as 2021?

Comment: I would also like to plot a time series may i know how?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `%Y`, use `%y`. :

```
time <- as.POSIXct(dataframe$DT, format="%m-%d-%y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution

```
time<-as.POSIXct(dataframe$DT,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

or

```
# install.packages("hms")

library(hms)
time <- as.hms(dataframe$DT)
```